# DataTemplate not drawing the View, but printing the typename for each ViewModel type it encounters in a Collection

Tags: c#, wpf

```
 <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ScreenViewModelCollection}">
            <ItemsControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type redScreenView:RedScreenView}">
                    <Grid>
                        <redScreenView:RedScreenView/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type greenScreenView:GreenScreenView}">
                    <Grid>
                        <greenScreenView:GreenScreenView/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>

            </ItemsControl.Resources>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Instead of drawing the View for its ViewModel, it prints the namespace that the View belongs to! 
But using an ItemTemplate works for just one of them. And ItemTemplate can't have more than one content :(

Comment: It's not a namespace, it is a type name for which you don't have corresponding template. Update your question with that type(s) name please.

Comment: @invisible thanks.. so how do i add the corresponding template. it appears i do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DataTemplates` are for `Views` while I suspect your `ScreenViewModelCollection` contains `ViewModels`.

You just need to make the `DataType` properties be `ViewModels` instead of `Views`

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myViewModels:RedScreenViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        <redScreenView:RedScreenView/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myViewModels:GreenScreenViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        <greenScreenView:GreenScreenView/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: you are absolutely brilliant! 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

i miss the definition for redScreenView/greenScreenView namespace, type of ScreenViewModelCollection, xaml for ItemsControl.ItemTemplate - so i just assume:

EDIT: pls look at your xaml i think you has some typos in there. the **DataType** for your DataTemplates should be the viewmodel. the content of the datatemplate the view of course.

nevertheless the **local** define the namespace and have to be in your window/usercontrol definition. e.g.

```
 <UserControl xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyWpfApplication1.MyTest.ViewModels" 
              xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyWpfApplication1.Controls.Views" 


    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ScreenViewModelCollection}">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:RedScreenViewModel}">
                <Grid>
                    <views:RedScreenView/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GreenScreenViewModel}">
                <Grid>
                    <views:GreenScreenView/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

does this ItemTemplate work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not. it is still printing the namespaces for each type of ViewModel object it encounters in the Collection